# Oozie supress logging from shell job action?

Tags: shell, logging, oozie

I have a simple workflow (see below) which runs a shell script. The shell script runs pyspark script, which moves file from local to hdfs folder.

When I run the shell script itself, it works perfectly, logs are redirect to a folder by > spark.txt 2>&1 right in the shell script.

But when I submit oozie job with following workflow, output from shell seems to be supressed. I tried to redirect all possible oozie logs (-verbose -log) > oozie.txt 2>&1, but it didn't help.

The workflow is finished successfuly (status SUCCESSEDED, no error log), but I see, the folder is not copied to hdfs, however when I run it alone (not through oozie), everything is fine.

```
<action name="forceLoadFromLocal2hdfs">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
  <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
      <value>${queueName}</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
  <exec>driver-script.sh</exec>
  <argument>s</argument>
  <argument>script.py</argument>
  <!-- arguments for py script -->
  <argument>hdfsPath</argument>
  <argument>localPath</argument>
  <file>driver-script.sh#driver-script.sh</file>
</shell>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
```

Thx a lot!

EDIT: Thx to the advice I found full log under the

```
yarn -logs -applicationId [application_xxxxxx_xxxx]
```

Comment: Oozie jobs are run inside a YARN container, with StdErr / StdOut redirected to the **YARN logs** for that container (with a whole lot of Oozie debugging info also injected in StdOut; your app output gets a specific prefix so that you can `grep` it out of the mess).

Comment: Cf. my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732 for details about how to access these logs from the YARN command line. Or, use the HUE dashboard to click your way from Oozie workflow to Oozie action, to YARN application, then to YARN application logs.

Comment: Thx. I did the yarn -logs ... thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to the advice I found full log under the

```
yarn -logs -applicationId [application_xxxxxx_xxxx]
```